# Javascript splice last element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr)
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr = arr.splice(4, 1)
console.log(arr)
//[5]
```

I want to remove only the last element. Why does it remove every element except the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to omit the assignment.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(...arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.splice(4, 1);
console.log(...arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you like just to delete the last one, you could take a negative index with [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). This works for any other index from the end.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(...arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.splice(-1, 1);
console.log(...arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the array in place and returns the removed portion. You should not reassign the removed portion to the variable.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.splice(4, 1)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

`splice` alters the array and returns the removed item(s) in a new array.

By the way, you should use [**`pop`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) which is better suited for this like so:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
```

`pop` removes the last item of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The splice method takes two parameters: a beginning index (inclusive) and an ending index (exclusive). The below will do what you described.

arr = arr.splice(0, 4)

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) may accept 3+ parameters (if you use it to replace items)

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general approach:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.splice(arr.length - 1);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the last arr element by splice(-1), then you stored that value (5) into a variable (newArr). The original array now values [1, 2, 3, 4].

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let newArr = arr.splice(-1);

console.log(arr)    //[1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(newArr)  //[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are reassigning the arr to the spliced value, which is [5]. the way you should do it is,

```
 var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     console.log(arr)
   //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     arr.splice(4, 1)
     console.log(arr)
   //[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This should give you the result you are looking for;

Answer (score 1):

The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed items in the form of an array.

Syntax :
let arrDeletedItems = array.splice(starting_index , index to which you want to add or remove an item , item 1 , item 2 , item 3 ...so on   )

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.splice(4, 1)

**so in your case, you are starting from index 4 which means the value "5" and you are removing the 1st element that starts from index 4 which is the value '5'. So the splice method would return a new array (as it returns a new array of the removed elements) containing only 5.**

To get back an array containing all the elements except the last element 5 you should write :
**arr = arr.splice(0,4)**
which means that start from index 0 and remove elements till index 4.

Answer (score 0):

Splice method returns the removed item(s) in an array so what is happening is you are assigning the returned to the original array. Instead do this

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arr);
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.splice(4, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice modifies array in place and returns removed part as a new array.
To get expected result you want to use expression:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr)
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.splice(4, 1)
console.log(arr)
//[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the last element from the array with rest operator

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const [ ...newArray, last ] = array
```